# load page into the webBrowser and grab HTML

Tags: c#, browser, html-parsing, web-scraping

I need to load the page into the webBrowser, wait for this page to load (including the ajax) and then grab the HTML of that page.

I tried this, but it seems to be not working as intended. Any help would be great!

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.mysite.com");
String htmldoc = webBrowser.DocumentText;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to DocumentCompleted...

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string htmldoc = webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
}
```

That should do the trick.